# Does Google People API support ability to query

Tags: google-api, google-people-api

Does google people api support the ability to query?  Currently, the older api contact google api allows you to use a query parameter "q" to do a simple text search.  Was wondering if people api supports this?

Thanks,
Derek

Comment: Hi. I was wondering the same. So How did you do to find a people by names for example? Did you use the older Google Contact API?

Comment: For other people who might need a better answer than "wait", I wrote a small blog post explaining how to use the old deprecated API https://medium.com/@emilefugulin/building-a-google-contacts-integration-with-search-in-2020-f9fffb9315a8

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Google People API currently does not support doing such a query. That functionality is one of the feature requests.

Comment: Am I thick, or does this not seem like it should already be included?

Comment: How do I do querying contacts in this case? Can I use contacts API until people API supports this?

Comment: What is the plan when deprecating the Contacts API? Does Google have the plan to support querying(Similiar to www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?q=tracy) in People API?

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/73864682 is tracking this feature.

Comment: @MattMcCallum I guess the only way for now is, retrieve all contacts on your application and do a search by yourself! In my case it sucks, bringing 10.000 contacts is too damm slow!

Comment: An alternative way is to retrieve all the ressourceName(ID) and stock them on local DB When you create a contact by API, make sure to stock also this ID somewhere linked with the contact on local DB. In this way you can always matching with this contact later.

Comment: The other alternative is to use the deprecated API to build it, it is not great but if you don't have the luxury to wait its the best current solution.