# How to search contact using Google People API

Tags: google-people-api

I am using google people API.For that I am using java client library.
I can do list,add,update,get contacts,But I can't **search** the contact by using people API.For example If I want to fetch the contacts by phone number start with 
 (+919500) or Name start with letter "M" . how to achieve this? 
Please help me to find the solution for this.

Note:
I don't want the result using Contact API v3 or Google + because these API are deprecated.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far and what error you are getting

Comment: I tried in google API explorer and java client library for people API operation
All the option(List,get,update,delete) are working expect Search.I didn't find any API or Library method for search option

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Google People API support ability to query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41840383/does-google-people-api-support-ability-to-query)